# Compare many rows of data (fast)

Tags: r, data.table

How can pairs of rows of data be compared very fast? Here is an MWE, but as I have almost 10,000 rows (amount.of.baskets), it is way too slow.

The MWE calculates how many fruits need to be added or subtracted when going from one basket to another.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
amount.of.baskets <- 10
the.baskets <- data.table(apples=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), oranges=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), pears=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), bananas=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), pineapples=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), avocados=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), nectarines=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), limes=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), cherries=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE), melons=sample(x=c(0:9), amount.of.baskets, replace=TRUE))

basket.diff.table <- NULL
for (from.i in 1:amount.of.baskets) {
    for (to.i in 1:amount.of.baskets) {
        tmp.i <- rbind(((-1)*the.baskets[from.i, ]), the.baskets[to.i, ])
        tmp.sum <- data.table(t(colSums(tmp.i)))
        tmp.sum[, c("from.basket", "to.basket"):=list(from.i, to.i)]
        basket.diff.table <- rbind(basket.diff.table, tmp.sum)
    }
}
```

basket.diff.table is the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For applying a function to all combinations of two vectors, you can usually use `outer`.

```
outer_diffs <- lapply(
  the.baskets,
  FUN = function(x) {
    as.vector(outer(x, x, "-"))
  }
)

str(outer_diffs)
# List of 10
#  $ apples    : int [1:100] 0 5 2 6 7 -2 3 6 3 2 ...
#  $ oranges   : int [1:100] 0 -5 -3 -4 -8 -1 -7 -9 -6 0 ...
#  $ pears     : int [1:100] 0 -2 -2 1 -2 -1 -3 -3 -6 -7 ...
#  $ bananas   : int [1:100] 0 0 -3 -2 -9 -5 -2 -7 -6 -7 ...
#  $ pineapples: int [1:100] 0 3 3 2 0 0 1 3 1 7 ...
#  $ avocados  : int [1:100] 0 4 7 1 5 2 1 7 8 3 ...
#  $ nectarines: int [1:100] 0 -6 -3 -4 2 -2 2 2 1 -2 ...
#  $ limes     : int [1:100] 0 -1 0 -7 -3 -5 -4 -1 -4 -6 ...
#  $ cherries  : int [1:100] 0 4 2 5 -1 2 7 6 6 -1 ...
#  $ melons    : int [1:100] 0 5 2 5 2 0 6 -1 3 4 ...

basket.diff.table <- as.data.table(outer_diffs)
basket_indices <- seq_len(nrow(the.baskets))
basket.diff.table[, ":="(
  from.basket = rep(basket_indices, each  = nrow(the.baskets)),
  to.basket   = rep(basket_indices, times = nrow(the.baskets))
)]

basket.diff.table[1:5]
#    apples oranges pears bananas pineapples avocados nectarines limes cherries melons from.basket to.basket
# 1:      0       0     0       0          0        0          0     0        0      0           1         1
# 2:      5      -5    -2       0          3        4         -6    -1        4      5           1         2
# 3:      2      -3    -2      -3          3        7         -3     0        2      2           1         3
# 4:      6      -4     1      -2          2        1         -4    -7        5      5           1         4
# 5:      7      -8    -2      -9          0        5          2    -3       -1      2           1         5
```

**Update:**

I'm leaving the above as my answer because it's more of a step-by-step demonstration of the solution. But, as @Henrik points out, this code can be shortened and sped up by doing more with the `data.table` package. His version:

```
n <- nrow(the.baskets)
basket.diff.table2 <- the.baskets[, c(
  lapply(.SD, function(x) as.vector(outer(x, x, "-"))),
  CJ(from.basket = 1:n, to.basket = 1:n)
)]
```

Comment: Wow. My code that would need hundreds of hours was sped up to just a few seconds. Impressive. Thanks!

Comment: Or slightly more compact: `n <- nrow(the.baskets)`; `basket.diff.table2 <- the.baskets[ , c(lapply(.SD, function(x) as.vector(outer(x, x, "-"))),
                                           CJ(from.basket = 1:n, to.basket = 1:n))]`. (a bit faster on `amount.of.baskets <- 10000`)

Comment: @Henrik I've added your version to the answer.  Hope that's okay.